# Separate login auth for admin

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, routes

I am successfully able to generate login for normal users. Now, I want to have same  endpoint `/login` for my login screen for both normal user and admin. I want to create **user-admin** with fixed email and flexible password with the token generated will be fixed .

I am new in Node.JS backend routing.

This is my **login route**:-

```
router.post('/login' , (req, res, next) => {

    User.find({email: req.body.email})
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
        if(user.length < 1) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: "Auth failed. User not found."
            })
        }
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) =>{
            if (err) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                message: "Auth failed. Check email and password"
                });             
            }   
            if (result){
            const token = jwt.sign( 
                {
                    email: user[0].email,
                    userId: user[0]._id
                },
                process.env.JWT_KEY,
                {
                    expiresIn : "1h"
                });
                return res.status(200).json({
                message: "Auth Successful",
                token : token
                });
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        if (err.code == 500)
                    res.status(500).send(["Something went wrong in login"]);
            else
            return next(err);
    });
});
```

*What are the things I need to add for my admin portion ?*

**EDIT:-**

**user.model**

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName : {
                type: String,
                required: "Full name can't be empty"
                },
    email :     {
                type: String,
                required: "Email can't be empty",
                unique: true
                },
    password :  {
                type: String,
                required: "Password can't be empty",
                minlength: [6 ,"Password must be atleast 6 character long"]
                },  
    phoneNumber :   {
                type: String,
                required: "Reqired for further contact.Can't be empty"
                },
    saltSecret: String 
});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**user.controller**

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
    module.exports.register = (req, res, next) =>{  

        var user = new User();
        user.fullName = req.body.fullName;
        user.email = req.body.email;
        user.password = req.body.password;
        user.phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
        user.save((err, doc) =>{
            if(!err)
                res.send(doc);
            else{
                if (err.code == 11000)
                        res.status(422).send(["Entered duplicate email address. Please check"]);
                else
                return next(err);
                }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional field `role` to the `Users` collection which can contain values `user` or `admin` (Or array of values if there are more roles).

Then, when you create the JWT token, you can add the `role` field to it.

```
const token = jwt.sign( 
{
    email: user[0].email,
    userId: user[0]._id,
    role: user[0].role
},
process.env.JWT_KEY,
{
    expiresIn : "1h"
});
```

Now, you can use this value to identify if the logged in user is admin or not.

You may need to create a new API for converting a user to admin (change the role field) or do it directly in the database depending on your requirement.

If you want to handle the admin logic entirely through code (without any modification to db) and you already know the email id of the user whom you want to assign as admin, then you can use the following logic.

```
const adminEmail = "admin@example.com";
const role = user[0].email===adminEmail? "admin" : "user";
const token = jwt.sign( 
{
    email: user[0].email,
    userId: user[0]._id,
    role
},
process.env.JWT_KEY,
{
    expiresIn : "1h"
});
```

Comment: Ok got it. But I have no idea how to assign a user to admin. I don't want to use database handle directly. I need to do it from my code.  I am using mongodb . I don't have any field as role in `Users`.

Comment: You have to modify the code that creates a user to include ```role``` along with other details.

Comment: So in database do I need to create separate admin table ? Or I can do it in same users table ?

Comment: You don't need to create a new table. All you need to do is add a new field in existing users collection. For ordinary user, the role should be "user". For admin user, the role should be "admin".

Comment: But I am not hard coding any user details. I  am confused in this part only as it is not hard coded. I am adding `user.model` and `controller` in EDITS. Please check and suggest

Comment: I have updated the answer to include an alternate logic if you want to handle the case without altering db.

Comment: getting error in this `const role = user[0].email===adminEmail? "admin" : "user";` as Unexpected identifier

Comment: That was a type. I have updated the code. ```const adminEmail = "admin@example.com";```

Comment: Yes i have corrected it . So how will i know if I have assigned this user with email id as an admin ?